# mv multiple files from different folders from specific date

Tags: mv

I have 3 folders `f1`, `f2` and `f3`.

How can I move every file from `f1` and `f2` that the dates are from the 22 jun 2016 till the 21 of september 2018  to the folder `f3`, in one command maybe using `mv`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've tagged with [ubuntu](/questions/tagged/ubuntu) I am going to assume GNU tools

```
find f1 f2 -maxdepth 1 -type f -newermt 2016-06-22 ! -newermt 2018-09-21 -exec echo mv -t f3 {} +
```

I may have the dates wrong by ±1 day on each side - please check this and adjust accordingly. When you are happy you can see that the `mv` command has received the correct files, remove the `echo` prefix.

Comment: thanks it worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload age
mv (f1|f2)/*(.e[age 2016-06-22 2018-09-21]) f3/
```

(note that it matches on files (regular files only with the `.` glob qualifier) last modified between the *start* of those 2 days. If you also want to move the files modified any time on 2018-09-21, you'll need to change the second date to 2018-09-22).